# Did Sofia truly like Cruise's character in Vanilla Sky?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, vanilla-sky

Just saw Vanilla Sky and am a bit lost. Was Sofia showing up at Cruise's character's funeral crying real or part of the Lucid Dream?

Did Sofia really love him or was it just the dream?

Answer (score 3):

> Was Sofia showing up at Cruise's character's funeral crying real or part of the Lucid Dream?

Yes, that was real. This scene showing Sofia at David's funeral wasn't apart of his Lucid Dream, it was a continuation from David's flashback of him killing himself.

When Sofia walked into David's apartment she looked at the door frame, the broken guitar where she and David had their first conversation, the people standing around who were also at that first party, and her thoughts/emotions about David came back to her. As a result she began tearing up, and then Edmund Ventura (the guy in the elevator with David) says,

> VENTURA: It was Sofia who never fully recovered. It was she somehow knew you best. And like you, she never forgot that one night where true love seemed possible.

So, I interpret her crying as a kind of "what could have been" instead of a "what once was".

---

> Did Sofia really love him or was it just the dream?

No, I don't believe she did.

The only actual amount of time that David and Sofia spent together was that first night/morning at his party, and then when she, David and Brian all go out to the club (which was a terrible experience for Sofia considering that she literally ran away from David afterwards).

The morning after the club, when David is laying on the street curb and Sofia picks him up, is the moment when David chose to begin his Lucid Dream life. From there on and for the rest of the film, all interactions between Sofia and David were apart of his dream. That's why her attitude/actions towards him were nothing but unconditional love.

Comment: If Sofia didn't think he might have been the One why did that guy say "she never recovered". And, why did Sofia run away from David at the club when he was talking to her but before this Sofia spends all her time in the club looking for David?

Comment: @verve Sofia *did* initially believe that her and David could have true love. When they spent the night together at her apartment she was really into him, and vise versa. However, after David's car accident and due to his face disfigurement, it really changed his attitude/behavior. When David first arrived at the club he had that mask on, which really discomforted Sofia and weirded Brian out. Once David and his friends talked about it, David got a kind of attitude and starting drinking a lot, then he confronted Sofia and it was really awkward. Because of this, afterwards, she ran away.